# Is there an app that will let me see aggregate stats on questions associated with a tag?

Tags: support, app-request

In particular, I'd like to see/graph views for all questions tagged 'foo'.  Seems like something someone must already have done, but search didn't help me find it easily.

Answer (score 1):

Are you after something like this?
http://hewgill.com/~greg/stackoverflow/stack_overflow/tags/

Comment: The graph only seems to go up to November 2011 :(

Answer (score 0):

I'm working on something like this at [www.dao.af](https://www.dao.af).  I'm using SE tags and adding more from the IBM Watson NLU.